# In VS code is there option to include files from some folders AND filter by extension/name of file?

Tags: search, visual-studio-code, file-search

Using Visual Studio Code, we have a project with structure of folders. In the folders there are **json files** which contains various strings and some additional files. Does VS code allow such search, that all applies, so we:

- Find the text specified in **search field**
- Only files from such path/folder will be visible
- Only files that have some extension/name will be visible

Generally I'm asking if there is some regex/other special char available for search-field **files to include**.

---

What I expect (what I'm trying) to enter in Search-box of VS Code:

[image: VS code screenshot of search]

---

Example of folder structure:

```
base
|-- A
|   |-- AA
|   |   `-- conf.json
|   |-- AB
|   |   `-- conf.json
|   `-. conf.json
|-- B
|   |-- BA
|   |   |-- BAA
|   |   |   `-. conf.json
|   |   `-. conf.json
|   |-- BB
|   |   `-. conf.json
|   |-- BC
|   |   |-- BCA
|   |   |   `-. conf.json
|   |   `-. conf.json
|   `-. conf.json
|-- C
    `-. conf.json
```

---

Comment: It looks like you want `./base/A/**/*conf.json`.  It isn't clear what these file names are : `. conf.json`?

Comment: Hm, yes, I missed that and didn't find reference elsewhere that I can use this.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating answer, since real answer creator (Mark) just added it in comment. String required to be entered is:

```html
./base/A/**/*conf.json
```

Reason for that is that the `**` are used for anything that can be in the tree structure (for multiple folders), where `*` just fills the space up to the file name between `/` and start/end.